# How do I cover up small holes in plaster ceiling?

Tags: repair, drywall, plaster

I accidentally punched these on the ceiling while moving stuff around. They're around half a centimeter in diameter, and the ceiling seems to be plaster.

How can I mask/cover these up the most subtly?

[image: Plaster holes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half a centimeter? In that case, spackle, sand, and paint. They make color changing spackle (pink to white) so you know when it's dry. Apply with a flat edge (e.g. a putty knife). Don't oversand, just enough to knock any rough edges off. And since the paint has an orange peel look, use a small roller for the touch-up.

Comment: I'm not even going to try before accepting this answer. Thank you so much. I will come back to confirm the results, for reference purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell if it's a straight orange-peel or a knockdown texture. Either way, BMitch's spackle-sand-paint procedure is the way to go, possibly with a little extra texturing to make it not immediately evident there's been a repair.